# Execute SQL written in a textbox with VBA

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

With reference to this question: [Avoid new line seperators in mySQL query within VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63841866/avoid-new-line-seperators-in-mysql-query-within-vba-code), I wanted to execude a `SQL` statement that is written in a `textbox` in the Excel-File. 
Therefore, I created a `textbox` called `SqlQuery1` looking like this:

[image]

---

In the `VBA` I refered to the textbox within the `SqlString`:

```
Sub Get_Data_from_DWH ()

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=XX.XXX.XXX.XX; DATABASE=bi; UID=testuser; PWD=test; OPTION=3"
    conn.Open
    
    SqlString = ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Shapes("SqlQuery1").OLEFormat.Object.Text
                            
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic

    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    
End Sub
```

---

However, I get `runtime error 438` on the `SqlString`. 
Do you have any idea what I need to change to make it work?

Comment: Divide problematic code string to separate steps. `SET wbk = ThisWorkbook: SET sh = wbk.Sheet1: SET shp = sh.Shapes("SqlQuery1"): SET of = shp.OLEFormat: SET obj = of.Object: SET SqlString = obj.Text` - what statement fails?

Comment: 'MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver' is quite outdated. If MySQL Server is 5.6 or newer use 'MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver' as 8.0.21 contains several bug fixes e.g on parameters. If older MySQL Server use 5.3.14 (supports Server 4.1 to 5.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Thisworkbook.Sheet1` is not a valid object path, try instead:

```
SqlString = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("SqlQuery1").OLEFormat.Object.Text
```

Or just

```
SqlString = Sheet1.Shapes("SqlQuery1").OLEFormat.Object.Text
```

And make sure the sheet is definitely named "Sheet1"

Also, you need to change

```
rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic
```

to this:

```
rs.Open SqlString, conn, adOpenStatic
```

And you should probably use

```
Dim SqlString as String
```

at the start of the routine

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track here and I can see that you've tried solving this error! :-)

Your issue is with the `rs.Open` part, as far as I can see. I've shuffled your code around  a bit. As far as I can see, you did not add the ADODB.Command part. I've added this in the code snippet below.

A word of advice to save time in larger modules; declare your connection as a private global string at the beginning, so you can access it later on in the module.

```
Private Const CONNECTION As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=XX.XXX.XXX.XX; DATABASE=bi; UID=testuser; PWD=test; OPTION=3"
    
Sub Get_Data_from_DWH()


    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim conn As ADODB.CONNECTION
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    
    Set conn = New ADODB.CONNECTION
    conn.Open CONNECTION
    conn.CommandTimeout = 900
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    
    
    If Not conn.State = ADODB.adStateOpen Then GoTo Bugcatcher
    
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = CONNECTION
    cmd.CommandText = ws.Shapes("TextBox 2").OLEFormat.Object.Text
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    
        
    ws.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
        
    
        
Bugcatcher:
        Exit Sub
        
    
End Sub
```